# Why is my functional test not matching my manual testing?

Tags: 8, testing

I have a [Drupal 8 module for banning users based on country](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_ban).

In it, I have the following test.

```php
public function setUp() {
  parent::setUp();
  $this->drupalLogin($this->adminSitesUser);
}

public function testCompleteBan() {
  // node/1.
  $this->addBanNode("Read only page");
  // node/2.
  $this->addBanNode("Complete ban page");
  $this->drupalGet(IP_BAN_ADMIN_FORM_PATH);
  $edit = [
    // Set the United States to Read Only
    // 0 = no action / 1 = Read Only / 2 = Complete Ban.
    'ip_ban_US' => 2,
    // Set the test IP address to a known Google US address.
    'ip_ban_test_ip' => '66.249.84.22',
    // Configure the paths for read-only and complete ban.
    'ip_ban_readonly_path' => '/node/1',
    'ip_ban_completeban_path' => '/node/2',
  ];
  $this->drupalPostForm(IP_BAN_ADMIN_FORM_PATH, $edit, t('Save configuration'));
  $this->assertOptionSelected('edit-ip-ban-us', 2, 'Complete ban set correctly in country list table.');
  // Should be redirected to complete ban page after logout.
  $this->drupalGet('user/logout');
  $this->assertUrl('node/2');
}
```

However, I get an error on the last line (`assertURL()`):
"Expected 'http://d8.dev/node/2' matches current URL (http://d8.dev/). Value 'http://d8.dev/' is equal to value 'http://d8.dev/node/2'."

It seems as if the page is not redirected on logout the way it is when manually testing with an extremely minimal installation and using the exact same settings (including permissions)/workflow as the tests.

Note all the form-based tests are working as well.

Any idea why this is not working in D8? (It works fine in D7.)

Comment: It's possible WebTestBase doesn't handle the symfony redirect in the same way. maybe try `assertResponse(302)`.

Comment: Okay I changed my event subscriber to middleware because of another problem I was having, and that seemed to solve the issue of the redirect not working, but now I'm getting a different error: "GET /node/2 returned 0 (0 bytes)" for the line `$this->drupalGet('user/logout');`, and "Expected 'http://d8.dev/node/2' matches current URL (/node/2). Value '/node/2' is equal to value 'http://d8.dev/node/2'" for the last line. Something's still amiss.

Comment: I remember running into this because either my VM did not have a hosts entry for the DNS i was using and/or the http_request_fails option or whatever needed to be set to FALSE.

Comment: I have a valid VM (and have added the trusted_hosts_patterns just in case), and that didn't help. I grepped the code base for http_request_fails, and came up empty.

Comment: Not trusted hosts pattern - `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Ahh I do have /etc/hosts configured correctly; still now sure about http_request_fails.

Comment: `drupal_http_request_fails` was a Drupal 7 variable. Sorry. This issue is personally frustrating because I've run into it several times. :|  One final thing to check is to make absolutely sure all dependencies are installed during the test run.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion failure looks as though the testing framework isn't following the double redirect (from `/user/logout` to `<front>` and thence to `/node/2`). Maybe explicitly request the front page after logging out?

Ie.

```
$this->drupalGet('user/logout');
$this->drupalGet('<front>');
$this->assertUrl('node/2');
```